# Laravel 4: Query to Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a query builder that works like this:

```
$query = DB::table($tablename);

if($keyword!=""){
    $query->where($field,'like','%'.$keyword.'%');
}

$query->get();
```

How can I convert it into eloquent?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

In your model make a query scope like:

```
//code to be written in your model  

public function scopeGetdata($field,$keyword){

      return  $query->where($field,'like','%'.$keyword.'%');

}
```

Let say our model name is *Custom* .
Now use this as follows:

```
Custom::Getdata($fieldname,$keyword)->get();
```

[Read this](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) to Explore more!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a model extending [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
           protected $table = 'MyTableName';
}
```

Then use query builder like

```
MyModel::where($field,'like','%'.$keyword.'%')->get();
```